# Swift NSViewController

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, nsviewcontroller

I'm new to cococa and swift, and I'm tring to create a custom ViewController.

```
class StatusUpdate : NSViewController {

  @IBOutlet var StatusView: NSView!
  @IBOutlet var eventsFoundCell: NSTextFieldCell!

  @IBAction func update(sender: AnyObject) {
      StatusView.hidden = false
      eventsFoundCell.stringValue = "A"
  }
}
```

The code as shown above is working as you would expect it.
But what I tring to do is to add an other function to that class like :

```
  func otherUpdate() {  
    eventsFoundCell.stringValue = "B"
  }
```

In order to update the `stringValue` of the `eventsFoundCell` variable.
So I could call it in an other class :

```
var update = StatusUpdate()
update.otherUpadte()
```

When calling `update.otherUpadte()` with in n other class,

I'm always getting an error like :

`Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

Any idea on show I could do this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in this line

```
 var update = StatusUpdate()
```

You are creating a new instance of `StatusUpdate`. The variable `StatusView` is not bound to any NSView

Answer (score 1):

You already got the answer, so this is recommendation only. It will make your Cocoa life way easier if you follow well established conventions. So, instead of:

```
@IBOutlet var StatusView: NSView!
```

you should write

```
@IBOutlet var statusView: NSView!
```

There are many cases in Cocoa where proper capitalisation (and style in general) are assumed in order for the frameworks to work.